# Is there any limitations for number of NKAssetDownload

Tags: ios, newsstand-kit

I am investigating Newsstand Kit. And I wonder how many Assets I can add to NKIssue? Is there any limitation or something like that?

```
NKAssetDownload *assetDownload = [nkIssue addAssetWithRequest:req];
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no limit mentioned in [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NKAssetDownload_Class/NKAssetDownload/NKAssetDownload.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NKAssetDownload) documents.

So you can add any number of [NKIssue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/NKIssue_Class/NKIssue/NKIssue.html) you want.